# 16.04 LTS wifi connection lost randomly every 5 minutes

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, dell, 16.04

First I had this issue described here [16.04 LTS wifi connection issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762198/16-04-lts-wifi-connection-issues) but nobody was able to provide a valid answer.

Recently this wifi connection issue gets even worse. I would lose wifi connection randomly about every 5 minutes on my computer(Dell XPS 8900 with skylake i7-6700 CPU and Samsung 950PRO SSD). The wifi icon would remain connected state while connection is lost. It looks like it would be  reconnected automatically after a while or I will have to reconnect manually.

Can somebody plz tell me what is going on here? Is it something wrong with my computer or just another bug with this version?

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of this terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2`

Comment: Same computer and same problem: sudo service network-manager restart does something

Comment: Details and works -> https://askubuntu.com/questions/762198/16-04-lts-wifi-connection-issues/768268#768268

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Finally, I was able to fix the issue.

1. Get details of your PCI wireless card by running the following

   ```
   sudo lshw -class network
   ```
2. Get your card model info according to the product line of the wireless interface. For instance, as you can see in the question description it says product: `RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter` so the model of my card is `RTL8723BE`
3. Open or create `/etc/pm/config.d/config` and add `SUSPEND_MODULES="rtl8723be"`(replace rtl8723be with your own model number) Then run

   ```
   echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=N" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
   ```

   and reboot.

Now your system should be able to reconnect automatically after sleep, and wifi connection never got lost once for me after doing this.

Comment: This fix is only for the specific adapter. It will not work for other models.

Comment: Does this work for RTL8723AE?

Comment: Didn't work for me as I have a different wifi card. However disabling ipv6 did the trick for me as described here https://askubuntu.com/questions/529347/how-do-i-keep-my-wifi-from-dropping-out - although the posting is for 14.04 it works with 16.04 too.

Comment: Didn't work for rtl8192cu - Ubuntu 17.10. It looked better but after 20 minutes it was disconnected again.

Comment: `as you can see in the question description it says product: RTL8723BE` - where is that question description? - I do no see Realtek mentioned in your question (the very reason it was marked as duplicate). If your issue was with Realtek post that in title.

Comment: worked for me on `RTL8101/2/6E`

Comment: @ericmjl I have tried with RTL8723AE and so far it seems to work. I will edit if it stops working, so if you're reading this, it works.