# Wifi keeps dropping on Dell XPS13 running Ubuntu 16.04, not sure how to use sudoedit on file

Tags: 16.04, wireless, internet, dell

Dell XPS 13 (7th gen i5), dual booting Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10.

Wifi works fine in Windows but in Ubuntu it gets disconnected every 5-10 minutes. The wifi icons on the top bar still appears to be connected. I have to manually click disconnect and connect again for wifi to work.

Tried a solution from [16.04 LTS wifi connection lost randomly every 5 minutes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766059/16-04-lts-wifi-connection-lost-randomly-every-5-minutes).

Did the following steps:

1. Got details of my PCI wireless card by running `sudo lshw -class network`
2. Took the code on the line that says `802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter: QCA6174`
3. Entered this into the terminal `sudoedit /etc/pm/config.d/config`
4. I was then prompted to a page within the terminal which says `GNU nano 2.5.3 File: /var/tmp/config.XXibmEDm`. Then I entered `SUSPEND_MODULES="QCA6174"` and I hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd> to save.
5. Was prompted to say if I want to save modified buffer: i hit Y
6. Was prompted `file name to write: /var/tmp/config.XXibmEDm`. I am stuck here, not sure which action to take. The options given were: `Get help/Cancel/DOS format/Mac format/Append/Prepend/Backup file/to files`

Comment: try to check this post
https://askubuntu.com/questions/529347/how-do-i-keep-my-wifi-from-dropping-out

Answer (score 0):

If you check terminal results for `iwconfig` I think you will find that power management is on and that is likely causing your issues.  You can disable power management with

```
sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
```

Reboot

Comment: Hi Jeremy, thanks! i just tried the above, managed to turn off power management but wifi still dropped after 5mins. Any idea what else could have gone wrong?

Comment: Check `iwlist scan | egrep -i 'ssid|cipher'` If your connection is using TKIP it may cause disconnects

Answer (score 0):

If your WiFi keeps dropping on Dell XPS13 running Ubuntu 16.04, troubleshoot by using sudoedit on the network configuration file. Navigate to the file using the terminal, apply changes, and save. Ensure accurate [syntax](https://www.google.com) to prevent connectivity issues, resolving potential conflicts affecting your WiFi stability on Ubuntu.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I had a very similar problem, turning off power management solved the issue for me. After logging into your wifi, turn off your power management. I use (sudo iwconfig wlp4s5 power off) currently I have to do this every time I log in, but works like a charm, no more dropped wifi connections.

Note: use iwconfig to get your wireless cards "wl" identifier, yours will most likely not be the same as mine. Hope this helps.