# More Wireless problems in 16.04 LTS (Connection Desperation)

Tags: networking, wireless

I know this question can be redundant, but I have not been able to fix it and I am starting to be desperate. Busy at work and without time to fix it, I lose connection every 5-10 min, my hair is getting whiter...

So I changed the router, and that is the origin of the problem. I have a dual boot with Windows.

1) I checked if the connection was stable. In Windows it was.

2) I did the IPV6 thing ([Change the wireless setting of IPv6](https://askubuntu.com/questions/529347/how-do-i-keep-my-wifi-from-dropping-out)).

3) I also tried this

`echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
sudo modprobe -rfv iwldvm
sudo modprobe -rfv iwlwifi
sudo modprobe -v iwlwifi`

4) Then I went for the best solution, following instructions here ([Wifi Connection lost randomly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766059/16-04-lts-wifi-connection-lost-randomly-every-5-minutes?noredirect=1&lq=1#_=_))

But when I run this I get an error

```
echo "options RTL8111/8168/8411 fwlps=N" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/RTL8111/8168/8411.conf
```

So now I do not know what to do next. I link (for being too long) [information from wireless info script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos) as recommended. http://paste.ubuntu.com/25024757/

Any other help, will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am writing this in order to hopefully help you and the inevitable searchers understand more about the process of identifying and correcting wireless problems. It is fruitless to blindly apply fixes found around the internet forums without verifying that your device is the same device referred to; either with `lspci` for internal devices or `lsusb` for USB devices. As you see, random fixes intended for devices other than your own are not ever helpful.

This is your wireless device:

```
ID 050d:2103 Belkin Components F7D2102 802.11n
```

And here are its drivers:

```
rtl8xxxu               73728  0
rtl8192cu              69632  0
rtl_usb                20480  1 rtl8192cu
rtl8192c_common        53248  1 rtl8192cu
rtlwifi                77824  3 rtl_usb,rtl8192c_common,rtl8192cu
mac80211              737280  4 rtl8xxxu,rtl_usb,rtlwifi,rtl8192cu
cfg80211              565248  2 mac80211,rtlwifi
```

I said driverS because there are two possibly conflicting drivers loaded. Let's blacklist one and see if connectivity improves. From the terminal:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist rtl8192cu"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

Reboot and tell us if conditions are improved.

Comment: Dear @Chili555, thanks a lot for the fast answer. Hours of wasting my time among different solutions without success and you come and you fix it in five minutes. Knowledge is power! The solution, after 5 hours looks good to me so far.  I have been using Ubuntu for the past 10 years and it is my main operating system (in laptop and in desktop computers). 99.9% of the time I am very happy with it, and I really congratulate all the comunity. The rest 0.01% I have small problems like this one, but they are complicated to fix sometimes, specially if you are slow as myself.

Comment: I am happy, as now I know enough about the system to be able to send some information so you can diagnose the problem fast. This looks stupid, but for some people is a big step ahead, I was intimidated by AskUbuntu for years as I was not able to send a proper question with information. If you come by the south of Spain, you have a free ride in my horses :) or any other way of showing love back, let me know. Best Regards and thanks again.

Comment: I'm very glad it's working as expected and thanks so much for the very kind comments! They made my day!