# 16.04 wifi gets disconnected every 30minutes

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, wireless

My wifi keeps getting disconnected every 30 minutes or so. It shows connected in the status bar but the connection is lost. I have to restart my system to get it working again.

Sometimes, the wireless device stops showing up after a restart. Then I have to shut down my system for about an hour and then start it to see the wireless device on running `lshw`

I tried the fix mentioned in the [Duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766059/16-04-lts-wifi-connection-lost-randomly-every-5-minutes?newreg=67682a6ab8354fadb23393ce8008252f) but it does not work for me. Kindly help me out!

Here is the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`

```
    03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b1] (rev c3)
    DeviceName: Intel Wireless AC 7260 802.11 ac 2x2 WiFi + BT 4.0 combo adapter
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 [8086:4070]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: And way did you try a solution for rtl8723be?

Comment: If the device disappears from `lspci` it means it is a hardware issue like a bad contact.

Comment: My product is Wireless 7260 on running `lshw` . So the rtl8723be solution wouldn't apply to me right?

Comment: It is a different device.

Comment: So should I try the duplicate question's solution by replacing rtl8723be with 7260?

Comment: What is the reason of placing a random solution to the question? As I said you have problems with your hardware, it can't be solved in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Try turning off Bluetooth if you can, stupid as it sounds -> it might do the trick.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/784629)

Comment: @Yaron: I believe that this is an attempt to answer the question although it could use sever improvement (see my other comment).

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)