# Ubuntu 16.04 wifi not working with Realtek RTL8821AE wireless card

Tags: networking, drivers, network-manager, realtek

1. Restarting network manager corrupted my network manager, after that I reinstalled fresh ubuntu
2. I also tried [this SO thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766059/16-04-lts-wifi-connection-lost-randomly-every-5-minutes), but nothing works for me
3. Wicd is also not robust
4. My Kernel version is **(4.10.0-28-generic)**
5. Here is my output of network details:

---

```
sudo lshw -C network

*-network               
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: enp2s0
   version: 10
   serial: d0:17:c2:12:1b:d7
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:47 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b2104000-b2104fff memory:b2100000-b2103fff
*-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: wlp3s0
   version: 00
   serial: b0:c0:90:69:0e:6d
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8821ae driverversion=4.10.0-28-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:51 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b2000000-b2003fff
*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 1
   logical name: enp0s20u8
   serial: 7e:b3:cd:e0:18:61
   capabilities: ethernet physical
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-   Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.238 link=yes multicast=yes
```

### Here is the output of lsusb

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 138a:0010 Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS Fingerprint sensor
Bus 001 Device 003: ID b49a:04f2  
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:57bc Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 24ae:2000  
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

### Output of dkms status

```
The program 'dkms' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
```

sudo apt install dkms

### here is the output of networks when it is not showing in network manager Applet using command    sudo iwlist wlp3s0 scan | grep -i SSID

```
ESSID:"Error"
ESSID:"Sagar_Network"                  
ESSID:"USER_5EE147"                    
ESSID:"CPH1701"
ESSID:"Moto E\xC2\xB3 POWER 4025"
ESSID:"AAAAAHz2tmkAQwHVRedmi"
ESSID:"Rconsultant"
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65353/discussion-on-question-by-prasun-kumar-dev-ubuntu-16-04-wifi-not-working-with-re).