# i lose my wireless connection but my modem works

Tags: networking, wireless, connection, modem

im using ubuntu 16.04 with windows 7 on my laptop . sometimes im losing connection with my modem , and i cant see again even though i turn off and then on  my laptop's wifi . it only starts working if i reboot my laptop . i didnt have a similar problem with my windows 7 yet  and i checked other devices on my lan when i have this problem on ubuntu . it was only me who had this problem. there are still a lot of things to learn for me , im already newbie :P . i hope you guys can help me :) .

Comment: hope this helps  http://askubuntu.com/questions/529347/how-do-i-keep-my-wifi-from-dropping-out

Comment: the problem was kinda different , it doesnt happen all the time .and when i lose connection , i cant see my device . i usually dont see any modem .but yea still i did those steps . lets see if i ll have the same problem again ! thanks buddy :)

Comment: @dhiya dude , thank you so much . I tried that and until now i didnt have the same problem . And i experienced that sometimes i saw my wifi symbol on desktop bar at the top as it is refreshing . it is like , it lost connection for a sec but then connected to the same modem immediately. it didnt even interrupt while im watching videos on youtube.Same thing was happening on another laptop with lxle , and it also worked on it as well . i know lxle is based on ubuntu and they even seem very same with terminal stuff  so tried it on lxle too :P ofcourse it also worked . again , thanks a lot :)