# (Ubuntu 17.04) Disconnecting from the internet intermittently

Tags: wireless, internet

I will get disconnected from the Internet at random times. The Wi-Fi symbol still shows that I am connected, but I am unable to use the Internet. The Wi-Fi works well on other devices.

I ran this script from  [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos).

```
wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info && chmod +x wireless-info && ./wireless-info
```

From the output, I removed the section NetworkManager profiles and changed my wifi name to be MYWIFI_2.4 and MYWIFI_5.0 for 2.4GHz and 5.0 GHz respectively.

I have uploaded the output [here](https://pastebin.com/L2MsTriU).

This is my first time posting here, so any other suggestions regarding formatting/information required are welcome.

Comment: This might be useful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/529347/how-do-i-keep-my-wifi-from-dropping-out

Comment: @pomsky It seems ok now after trying 2 methods in your link, will monitor for the next few days. The disconnects were rather intermittent, so can't tell yet if the issue has been rectified

Comment: After monitoring for the past few days, the disconnects are less intermittent but there are still random disconnects.