# I'm connected to Wi-Fi network but my internet keeps dropping randomly

Tags: wireless

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I have problem with wireless. It says it's connected all the time but randomly, every few minutes, internet is gone and after minute or two it comes back again. All other devices in my home (other computers, phones etc.) have internet all the time.

I ran the script I found on this forum and put it into this Ubuntu Paste bin: http://paste.ubuntu.com/25660911/

Can anyone offer me a solution? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Does it do that with all wireless networks? Do you have other Linux machines connected?

Comment: Yes, with all wireless networks and no, this is the only one.

Comment: See this for tips and hacks: https://askubuntu.com/q/529347/ and this [article](https://itsfoss.com/speed-up-slow-wifi-connection-ubuntu/).

Answer (score 0):

We notice this in your paste:

```
Address: <MAC 'RJNSL' [AC1]>
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=60/70  Signal level=-50 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"RJNSL"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000531e3c64c
                    Extra: Last beacon: 160ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
```

First, check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/crda
```

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Next, I'd set IPv6 to Ignore in Network Manager: http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/Installation_Guide/images/netconfig/network-connections-ipv6-ignore.png  This example is for ethernet, but you want wireless.