# HP Spectre 13-v130ng wireless connection stops working after a while

Tags: 16.04, wireless, kubuntu, hp

I have recently purchased a HP Spectre 13-v130ng. I installed Kubuntu 16.04.3, and everything works pretty well, except for that the WiFi connection just kind of stops working every once in a while. It still displays that the laptop is connected, but it can't resolve servers anymore. Is something wrong with my drivers or could this be a hardware issue?

Comment: This might come in handy: https://askubuntu.com/q/529347... and [this article](https://itsfoss.com/speed-up-slow-wifi-connection-ubuntu/).

Comment: I faced it with my wireless HP printer (D110). I have two wifi routers that provided connection SSID using the same name. This feature works with any device, but doesn`t work with HP Printers, so I have to disable it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.