# Wireless Network Keeps dropping out

Tags: wireless

I am using Ubuntu 17.04 alongside with windows 10. There is no wifi issue in Win 10. But when i use ubuntu internet stops working every now and then. It starts working again if I disable wifi and then enable again.
Is there anything I can do to stabalize this?

Comment: See if this helps: https://askubuntu.com/questions/529347/how-do-i-keep-my-wifi-from-dropping-out. Check this out too: https://itsfoss.com/speed-up-slow-wifi-connection-ubuntu/

Comment: What WiFi card do you use? What is the make and model of your computer?